# Pandas groupby using function variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
  iata               airport              city state country        lat  \
0  00M              Thigpen        Bay Springs    MS     USA  31.953765   
1  00R  Livingston Municipal        Livingston    TX     USA  30.685861   
2  00V           Meadow Lake  Colorado Springs    CO     USA  38.945749   
3  01G          Perry-Warsaw             Perry    NY     USA  42.741347   
4  01J      Hilliard Airpark          Hilliard    FL     USA  30.688012
```

I am trying to get the number of airports per state. For example if I have the function:

```
f(dataframe, state):
    result reuslt
```

Where state would be a state abbreviation, such as 'MA'. I am trying to group the dataframe by the input variable, such as state ('MA') to then get the number of airports per state.

When I use:

```
df.groupby(state)['airport'].value_counts()
```

or

```
df.groupby(state)['airport'].value_counts()/df['airport'].count()


df.groupby(['state'] == state)['airport'].value_counts()/df['airport'].count()
```

The last two are regarding the conditional probability a selected airport will be in that state.

It throws a Key Error: 'MA', which I think is due to the input variable not being recognized as a column, but a value in the column.

Is there a way to get the number of airports per state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Pandas's `nunique` to get the number of airports per state. The code is easier to read and remember.

To illustrate my point, I modified the dataset as follows, such that Florida has three more fictional airports:

`iata    airport                 city        state   country lat
0   00M     Thigpen Bay             Springs     MS      USA     31.953765
1   00R     Livingston Municipal    Livingston  TX      USA     30.685861
2   00V     Meadow Lake             Springs     CO      USA     38.945749
3   01G     Perry-Warsaw            Perry       NY      USA     42.741347
4   01J     Hilliard Airpark        Hilliard    FL      USA     30.688012
5   f234    Weirdviller             Chilliard   FL      USA     30.788012
6   23r2    Johnson                 Billiard    FL      USA     30.888012`

Then, we write:

`df.groupby('state').iata.nunique()`

to get the following results:

`state
CO    1
MS    1
TX    1
FL    3
NY    1
Name: iata, dtype: int64`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each record is an airport throughout, you can just count the records for each state / country combination:

```
df.groupby(['country','state']).size()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this as an explicit groupby apply:

```
In [11]: df.groupby("state")["airport"].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts() / len(x))
Out[11]:
state
CO     Meadow Lake             1.0
FL     Hilliard Airpark        1.0
MS     Thigpen                 1.0
NY     Perry-Warsaw            1.0
TX     Livingston Municipal    1.0
Name: airport, dtype: float64
```

or store the groupby and reuse it (probably this is faster):

```
In [21]: g = df.groupby("state")["airport"]

In [22]: g.value_counts() / g.size()
Out[22]:
state  airport
CO     Meadow Lake             1.0
FL     Hilliard Airpark        1.0
MS     Thigpen                 1.0
NY     Perry-Warsaw            1.0
TX     Livingston Municipal    1.0
Name: airport, dtype: float64
```

Comment: of course, all the conditional probabilities are 1.0 in this example (as there is only one airport in each state).

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work the way I intended with all your help. `a[state]` represents an input in the form of a state abbreviation ('MA'). This returns the probability of a randomly selected airport belonging to that state.

```
a = df.groupby('state').iata.nunique()
s = a.sum()
result = a[state]/s
return result
```